# Confusion regarding dimension of variety and rank of Jacobian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, jacobian, affine-varieties

I am getting the contradiction described below. I have been racking my brain since yesterday to figure out what the problem is here, but I just can't. I must be making some super silly mistake. Please help me figure it out.

$\textbf{Notation:}$ For any ideal $A \subseteq k[x_1,...,x_n]$, denote the variety of $A$ by $V(A)$. For any variety $V$, denote the vanishing ideal of $V$ by $I(V)$. If $A = (f_1,...,f_t)$ is a finitely generated ideal, define the Jacobian of A at a point $P \in k^n$ by $J_P(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(P) & \dots &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(P)\\
\vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial x_1}(P) & \dots &\frac{\partial f_t}{\partial x_n}(P)
\end{pmatrix}$.

$\textbf{The contradiction I got:}$

In $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,a,b,c]$, consider the ideals $A = \langle a^2+b^2+c^2,a(x+y+z),b(x+y+z),c(x+y+z)\rangle$ and $J = \langle a^2+b^2+c^2,x+y+z \rangle$.

Then, $A \subseteq J
\implies V(J) \subseteq V(A)$, where V(J) denotes variety of J

$\implies \dim V(A) \geq \dim V(J) \geq 6-2 = 4 \hspace{1cm} [\because \dim V(f_1,...,f_r) \geq n-r$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and here $n=6,r=2$]

$\implies\forall P \in V(A)$ , rank $J_P(I(V(A)) \leq 6 - \dim V(A)\hspace{0.4cm}$ [A proof of this is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256182/596347)
]

$\hspace{6.8cm}\leq 6-4=2$

Now obviously $A \subseteq I(V(A) \implies$ rank $J_P(A) \leq$ rank $J_P(I(V(A)) \hspace{0.5cm}\dots\dots(1)$ [I have given a proof of this at the end of this question]

$\implies$ rank $J_P(A) \leq 2 \hspace{1cm} \dots\dots(2)$

But if we take the point $P = (1,1,1,0,0,0) \in V(A)$ [here the coordinates are $x,y,z,a,b,c$-coordinates in given order], then $J_P(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial a}(P) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial b}(P) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial c}(P) &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(P) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(P) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}(P)\\
\vdots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_4}{\partial a}(P) & \frac{\partial f_4}{\partial b}(P) & \frac{\partial f_4}{\partial c}(P) &\frac{\partial f_4}{\partial x}(P) & \frac{\partial f_4}{\partial y}(P) & \frac{\partial f_4}{\partial z}(P)
\end{pmatrix}$, where $f_1 = a^2+b^2+c^2, f_2 = a(x+y+z), f_3 = b(x+y+z), f_4 = c(x+y+z)$.

The only three non-zero entries in the above matrix are $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial a}(P),\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial b}(P),\frac{\partial f_4}{\partial c}(P)$, which lie along a diagonal.

$\therefore$ rank $J_P(A) = 3$, which contradicts with $(2)$. Which step was wrong here?

$\textbf{Proof of (1):}$ We have to prove that for finitely generated ideals $A = \langle f_1,...,f_t\rangle$ and $B = \langle g_1,...,g_r\rangle$, if $A \subseteq B$, then rank $J_P(A) \leq$ rank $J_P(B)$ at any point $P \in V(B)$.

As $A \subseteq B$, for $1 \leq i \leq t$ express $f_i$ as $f_i = \sum_{j=1}^r g_jh_{ij}$

$\implies \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_k}(P) = \sum_{j=1}^r \left(\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_k}(P)h_{ij}(P) + g_j(P)\frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial x_k}(P)\right) = \sum_{j=1}^r \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_k}(P)h_{ij}(P)\hspace{0.2cm}$ [$\because g_j(P) = 0 \hspace{0.2cm} \forall P \in V(B)$]

$\implies$ A basis for row space of $J_P(B)$ gives a basis for row space of $J_P(A)$.

$\implies$ rank $J_P(A) \leq$ rank $J_P(B)$

Comment: "I am getting the contradiction described below. I have been racking my brains since yesterday to figure out what the problem is here, but I just can't. I must be making some super silly mistake. Please help me figure it out." If you want to use the Jacobian criterion and the proofs in HH, CH.I.5 you must assume that the ideals $A,B$ are prime. It seems that the ideal $A$ you define above is not prime.

Comment: @hm2020 Do you mean that rank $J_P(I(V(A))) \leq n - \dim V(A)$ only when A is prime?

Comment: $a(x+y+z)\in A$ but $a\notin A$ as well as $x+y+z\notin A$.

Comment: @EvansGambit I got that lmao. My question is: If A is not prime, rank $J_P(I(V(A)) \leq \dim V(A)$ is not true? I thought the inequality holds irrespective of what kind of variety V is.

Answer (score 1):

For $A=(xz, yz)$ in $k[x, y, z]$ union of z-axis and the x-y plane.

$I(V(A))=(xz, yz)$.

$\dim V(A)=2$ and $n=3$.

But $\operatorname{rank} J_{((0, 0, 1)}(I(V(A))=2$ which is not  $\leq 1=3-2=3-\dim V(A).$